# Error 1452 when trying to set up a stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to set up a stored procedure to fill out linking tables/ fill out the linking tables itself. But when trying to set it up I am getting:

> Error Code: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`movie_rentals`.`linking_personnel`, CONSTRAINT `linking_personnel_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `movie` (`movie_id`))

I am not sure on where I need to be setting the foreign key constraints.

The stored procedure is set up as

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_link;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test_link( IN film_title VARCHAR(35), IN first_name VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;
select movie_id from movie_rentals.movie where film_title=film_title;
select person_id from movie_rentals.personnel where first_name=first_name;
INSERT INTO linking_personnel(movie_id, person_id) VALUES (movie_id, person_id);
COMMIT;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

But when trying to `call` the procedure I get the error and it enters the wrong values into the table anyway.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the `movie_id` and `person_id` variables, and use `SELECT ... INTO variable` to assign them. But you can simply use the `SELECT` query as the source of data in the `INSERT` rather than using variables.

You also should name your procedure parameters differently from the table columns. Your condition `WHERE film_title = film_title` is always true because it's comparing the variable with itself, not with the table column.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_link;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test_link( IN p_film_title VARCHAR(35), IN p_first_name VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO linking_personnel (movie_id, person_id)
    SELECT movie_id, person_id
    FROM movie_rentals.movie
    CROSS JOIN movie_rentals.personnel
    WHERE film_title = p_film_title
    AND first_name = p_first_name;
    COMMIT;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```